# Using Windows Azure Relay Service Bus With Windows Phone

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-servicebusrelay

I set up a service with windows azure that works perfectly with console app

I wont past all my service code because it's alot but heres the client code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Determine the system connectivity mode based on the command line
            // arguments: -http, -tcp or -auto  (defaults to auto)
            ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = GetConnectivityMode(args);
            string serviceNamespace = "******";
            string issuerName = "*****";
            string issuerSecret = "*******************************************";

            // create the service URI based on the service namespace
            Uri serviceUri = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", serviceNamespace, "EchoService");

            // create the credentials object for the endpoint
            TransportClientEndpointBehavior sharedSecretServiceBusCredential = new TransportClientEndpointBehavior();
            sharedSecretServiceBusCredential.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider(issuerName, issuerSecret);            

            // create the channel factory loading the configuration
            ChannelFactory<IEchoChannel> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IEchoChannel>("RelayEndpoint", new EndpointAddress(serviceUri));

            // apply the Service Bus credentials
            channelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(sharedSecretServiceBusCredential);

            // create and open the client channel
            IEchoChannel channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
            channel.Open();


            Console.WriteLine("Enter text to echo (or [Enter] to exit):");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            while (input != String.Empty)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Server echoed: {0}", channel.Echo(input));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
                }
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            channel.Close();
            channelFactory.Close();
        }

        static ConnectivityMode GetConnectivityMode(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (string arg in args)
            {
                if (arg.Equals("/auto", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
                     arg.Equals("-auto", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return ConnectivityMode.AutoDetect;
                }
                else if (arg.Equals("/tcp", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
                     arg.Equals("-tcp", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return ConnectivityMode.Tcp;
                }
                else if (arg.Equals("/http", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
                     arg.Equals("-http", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return ConnectivityMode.Http;
                }
            }
            return ConnectivityMode.AutoDetect;
        }       
    }
```

Withi this code, everything is working fine, I run the service and then the client and when i send a msg through the client i can see it in the service screen...

I've tried using this code:

```
private void webClient_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (token == "")
        {
            token =
             e.Result.Split('&').Single(x => x.StartsWith("wrap_access_token=",
             StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Split('=')[1];
        }
        string decodedToken = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(token); 

    var uriBuilder =
    new UriBuilder("https://locations.servicebus.windows.net/EchoService");

    uriBuilder.Path += 
    string.Format("HelloWorld"); 

    var webClient = new WebClient();


    if (autho == "")
    {
        autho = string.Format("WRAP access_token=\"{0}\"", decodedToken);
    }
    webClient.Headers["Authorization"] = autho;
    webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += 
    (s, args) => ParseAndShowResult(args);
    webClient.DownloadStringAsync(uriBuilder.Uri);
}
   public void ParseAndShowResult(DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    string result = args.Result;

}

   private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       var webClient = new WebClient();
       string acsUri = "https://locations-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net/WRAPv0.9/";
       string data = string.Format("wrap_name={0}&wrap_password={1}&wrap_scope={2}",
       HttpUtility.UrlEncode("owner"),
       HttpUtility.UrlEncode("qP/TCHlDzIUidlHC4Q3xNgQn84CLmDx/lYFbDimhj/o="),
       HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://locations.servicebus.windows.net"));
       webClient.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
       webClient.UploadStringCompleted += webClient_UploadStringCompleted;
       webClient.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(acsUri), "POST", data); 
   }
```

But the only thing it does is returns an xml stating the list of services i have
What i need is to send a msg that the service will see

any help here?

Answer (score 0):

In the console app, your address prefix is `sb`, and for your phone app it is `https`. I am guessing you need to change it to `sb` to make it work.

So it should be:

```
new UriBuilder("sb://locations.servicebus.windows.net/EchoService");
```

Also, your console app does not use `HelloWorld` on the URI at all, so I am not sure why you are using it in the phone app.